# jQuery-Ui Ajax Tabs bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a **JSON** that returns from the server which tabs to build,
so I init them in my JS like this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs( 'ajaxOptions', { 
   timeout: 20000, 
   error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor){ 
       console.log( status, index, anchor );
   }
})
.tabs('add', item.CategoryLink, item.CategoryName);
```

Thing is, when I click a tab, and before it is done loading I click another tab,
the previous **request is aborted** and never called again when I click that first one again!
this is very bad, because it obviously didn't fetch the request, so what gives?
I tried bypassing this by setting:

`.tabs({ cache: false })`

but this is a bad thing to do, because I don't want to have a request each time again...
it should be cachced if response was sent.

*using `jquery-ui 1.8.1`*

Comment: I see there's an open ticket on that bug: http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround from the [bug tracker](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5465):
use this inside the tabs load event:

```
load: function(event, ui){
    $(ui.tab).data("cache.tabs",($(ui.panel).html() == "") ? false : true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the same XHR object for the AJAX call, thus canceling every previous request. This is, as far as I can see, unavoidable as you cannot manually create a `new` XHR request when using the `tabs` function.

Also, you have 20 (`timeout: 20000,`) second timeout on clicking of your tab. What use is that?

Hth

Comment: because I have tabs which takes a long time to load, so I'm giving them 20sec chance to respond, then I prompt an error. the only solution I can think of is to rewrite the Tabs myself